# How to print out only a certain content in the listview

Tags: android, json, listview

i have a listview which should show basically the whole content of my json.
But if the user clicks on a Button, the list view should only show only the items which contains this content, for example in my listview are the charts.
If the users clicks on the POP button, the listview should only show the Popsongs.

Comment: So... what is your specific question, where is your code, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Pass an updated list to your adapter with only pop songs and set notifyDataSetChanged for your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to implement a Filter (look up the filterable interface). You want to make a new list with only the items you are interested in, and show that in your listview/recyclerview

```
List<YourItemType> originalList;
void onClick(){
  List<YourItemType> filteredList = new ArrayList<YourItemType>();
  for(YourItemType item: originalList) {
     if(item.type = desiredType) {
          filteredList.add(item);
     }
  }
  adapter.setItems(filteredList);
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats it, how can i do this

Comment: I am not going to write the code for you, but you said you want to do this in the onClick() of a button, so one idea would be the following: when user clicks, you go through your list, and if an item is from the category you want, you add it to a new list. You then pass this new list to your adapter and invalidate.

Comment: Yeah no problem, i can write the code by myself but do you have some useful links etc because i dont know how to create a new list like you said.

Comment: List<T> yourOriginalList;; in your onClick method you then do something like this: List<T> filteredList = new ArrayList<T>(); and then you go through your original list and add just the items you need in the new list

Comment: See the edited answer. But you should do some research before asking, because there are a lot of questions just like yours on SO